# SoapClient::SomeFunction to SoapClient::__soapCall('SomeFunction')

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I send a request to `WSDL` server in this way:

```
$soap = new SoapClient('WSDL_URI');
$soap->SomeFunction(array('Param1' => 123, 'Param2' => 456));
```

it works fine, and `__getLastRequest` returns:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:SomeFunction>
            <ns1:Param1>123</ns1:Param1>
            <ns1:Param2>456</ns1:Param2>
        </ns1:SomeFunction>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but if I call `SomeFunction` by `__soapCall`, `WSDL` server brakes down and doesn't return a correct response.

```
$soap->__soapCall('SomeFunction', array('Param1' => 123, 'Param2' => 456));
```

`__getLastRequest` returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:SomeFunction/>
        <param1>123</param1>
        <param2>456</param2>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

you see, because requests are different, it doesn't work..

How to resolve it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to call `__soapCall` directly, as you shouldn't need to do so.  If you really have a use case, show us your `__soapCall` code

Comment: @ernie: question edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown in php documentation [SoapClient::__soapCall](http://php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.soapcall.php),

```
    $client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");

    $client->SomeFunction($a, $b, $c);
    // Or    
    $client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c));
```

So I think if you want to call the webservice with `__soapCall`, you should make the call like that:

```
$soap->__soapCall('SomeFunction', array(array('Param1' => 123, 'Param2' => 456)));
```